# Find common elements of two strings including characters that occur many times

Tags: python, string

I would like to get common elements in two given strings such that duplicates will be taken care of. It means that if a letter occurs 3 times in the first string and 2 times in the second one, then in the common string it has to occur 2 times. The length of the two strings may be different. eg

```
s1 = 'aebcdee'
s2 = 'aaeedfskm' 
common = 'aeed'
```

I can not use the intersection between two sets. What would be the easiest way to find the result 'common' ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are multiple ways in which you can get the desired result. For me the simplest algorithm to get the answer would be:

1. Define an empty `dict`. Like `d = {}`
2. Iterate through each character of the first string:
   if the character is not present in the dictionary, add the character to the dictionary. 
   else increment the count of character in the dictionary.
3. Create a variable as `common = ""`
4. Iterate through the second string characters, if the count of that character in the dictionary above is greater than 0: decrement its value and add this character to `common`
5. Do whatever you want to do with the `common`

The complete code for this problem:

```
s1 = 'aebcdee'
s2 = 'aaeedfskm' 

d = {}

for c in s1:
    if c in d:
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 1

common = ""

for c in s2:
    if c in d and d[c] > 0:
        common += c
        d[c] -= 1

print(common)
```

Comment: Thanks. Why one needs to check if `d[c] > 0` given that it is included in the if statement: `if c in d` ? If c is in d, then its value in the dictionary will be necessarily `> 0.` And yet, when I omit the part `d[c] > 0`, I do not get the right result.

Comment: It is necessary to include d[c] > 0 because: number of a character in s1 might be less than the number of same character in s2. So if we keep on subtracting without this condition then we might end up adding all occurrences of that character into the string "common"

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collection.Counter` and count each char in two string and if each char exist in two string using `min` of `list` and create a new `string` by join of them.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest
s1 = 'aebcdee'
s2 = 'aaeedfskm' 

# Create a dictionary the value is 'list' and can append char in each 'list'
res = defaultdict(list)


# get count of each char
cnt1 = Counter(s1) # -> {'e': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}
cnt2 = Counter(s2) # -> {'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'd': 1, 'f': 1, 's': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1}

# for appending chars in one step, we can zip count of chars in two strings, 
# so Because maybe two string have different length, we can use 'itertools. zip_longest'
for a,b in zip_longest(cnt1 , cnt2):
# list(zip_longest(cnt1 , cnt2)) -> [('a', 'a'), ('e', 'e'), ('b', 'd'), 
#                                    ('c', 'f'), ('d', 's'), (None, 'k'), 
#                                    (None, 'm')]

    # Because maybe we have 'none', before 'append' we need to check 'a' and 'b' don't be 'none'
    if a: res[a].append(cnt1[a])
    if b: res[b].append(cnt2[b])

# res -> {'a': [1, 2], 'e': [3, 2], 'b': [1], 'd': [1, 1], 'c': [1], 'f': [1], 's': [1], 'k': [1], 'm': [1]}

# If the length 'list' of each char is larger than one so this char is duplicated and we repeat this char in the result base min of each char in the 'list' of count char of two strings.
out = ''.join(k* min(v) for k,v in res.items() if len(v)>1)
print(out)
# aeed
```

We can use this approach for multiple string, like three strings.

```
s1 = 'aebcdee'
s2 = 'aaeedfskm' 
s3 = 'aaeeezzxx'
res = defaultdict(list)
cnt1 = Counter(s1) 
cnt2 = Counter(s2)
cnt3 = Counter(s3)
for a,b,c in zip_longest(cnt1 , cnt2, cnt3):
    if a: res[a].append(cnt1[a])
    if b: res[b].append(cnt2[b])
    if c: res[c].append(cnt3[c])
out = ''.join(k* min(v) for k,v in res.items() if len(v)>1)
print(out)
# aeed
```

Comment: Thanks. I hoped for a more elementary solution without using libraries. I do not understand everything in your code. The length of the two strings may be different, I edited the post. In that case I do not know how yo will use zip since you may than eventually skip common characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two arrays (length 26).
One array is for the 1st string and 2nd array is for the second string.

Initialize both the arrays to 0.

The 1st array's 0th index denotes the number of "a" in 1st string,
1st index denotes number of "b" in 1st string, similarly till - 25th index denotes number of "z" in 1st string.

Similarly, you can create an array for the second string and store the count of
each alphabet in their corresponding index.

s1 = 'aebcdee'
s2 = 'aaeedfs'
Below is the array example for the above s1 and s2 values

[image: Array after alphabet count]

Now you can run through the 1st String
s1 = 'aebcdee'

for each alphabet find the

`K =  minimum of ( [ count(alphabet) in Array 1 ], [ count(alphabet) in Array 2 ] )`
and print that alphabet `K` times.
then make that alphabet count to 0 in both the arrays. (Because if you dint make it zero, then our algo might print the same alphabet again if it comes in the future).

Complexity - O( length(S1) )

Note - You can also run through the string having a minimum length to reduce the complexity.
In that case Complexity - O( minimum [ length(S1), length(S2) ] )

Please let me know if you want the implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1="ckglter" 
s2="ancjkle" 
final_list=[] 
if(len(s1)<len(s2)): 
    for i in s1: 
            if(i in s2): 
                final_list.append(i) 
else: 
    for i in s2: 
            if(i in s1): 
                final_list.append(i) 
print(final_list)
```

you can also do it like this also, just iterate through both the string using for loop and append the common character into the empty list

Comment: Thanks. I do not understand the else condition. Do you mean `if(len(s1)>=len(s2))` ? If so, why ? The result that I get with your code is `'aaeed'`.

Comment: first you check if s1 elements are present in s2 and in else condition you check if s2 elements are present in s1